# Datatable tabletool pdf Export width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hello I have 35 columns in a single datatable . i am using table tools to export it to PDF .However `all the columns are rendered in one sheet as in without any X-scroll and the columns are crumpled together.`
I am using the following code. I hope you got my problem.

```
              {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sToolTip": "Download to pdf",
                    "sButtonClass": "fa fa-download ",
                    "sButtonText": "",
                    "mColumns": "all",
                    "sPdfSize": "tabloid",
                    "sTitle": gridConfig.pdfExportTitle,
                    "sMessage": gridConfig.pdfExportMsg
                }
```

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question, care to elaborate?

Comment: The problem is that all the 35 columns are rendered in one page without any scrollbar ..width of table is equal to width of page ...